# Почему я не могу могу импортировать пакет?

Tags: golang

Я только начал изучать Golang и сразу столкнулся с проблемой. Почему я не могу импортировать пакет? Я создал новый файл в директории MyDir. Написал в нем следующий код:

```go
package MyDir

var A uint16
```

В другом файле

```go
package main

import "lessons3/MyDir"

func main() {
    MyDir.A := 12
}
```

В консоли при компиляции пишет это:

```go
cannot find package "lessons3/MyDir" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/lessons3/MyDir (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/maksimalekseev/go/src/lessons3/MyDir (from $GOPATH)
```

Как это исправить ?

Comment: Если работаете в режиме `GOPATH`, читайте [«_How to write Go code_»](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). Если в режиме модулей, читайте [«_Modules: Quick Start_»](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#quick-start).

Comment: А "другой" файл где лежит?

Comment: @softland, лежит в той же директории, но при этом в другой папке